# Marklogic Roxy: Calling a javascript module from app_specific.rb

Tags: marklogic, roxy

I have a Marklogic 9 project that I'm configuring with Roxy. 
I've been following these examples: https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/wiki/Adding-Custom-Build-Steps

Basically, I have a server-side JS function that I want to call after deploy content. I have something like this:

# then you would define your new method

```
  def deploy_content
    # you can optionally call the original
    original_deploy_content

    # do your stuff here
    execute_query(%Q{
      xquery version "1.0-ml";
      xdmp:javascript-eval('var process = require("/ingestion/process.sjs"); process.postDeployContent();')
    },
    :db_name => @properties["ml.app-name"] + "-content")

  end
```

The xquery being called here evaluates fine when executed via query console. But when I call ml local deploy content, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 500 "Internal Server Error"
ERROR: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/error.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="error">
      <h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>
      <dl>
        <dt>XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: var process = require("/ingestion/process.sjs"); process.postDeployContent(); -- Module /ingestion/process.sjs not found</dt>
        <dd></dd>
        <dt>in [anonymous], at 1:14 [javascript]</dt>
        <dd></dd>
        <dt>at 3:6,
in xdmp:eval("var process = require(&amp;quot;/ingestion/process.sjs&amp;quot;); proce...") [javascript]</dt>
        <dd></dd>
        <dt>in /eval, at 3:6 [1.0-ml]</dt>
        <dd></dd>
      </dl>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is the module not found when running via xquery from app_specific.rb?

Or... is there a better way to call a JS module function from here. Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the xquery side, so I just called a JS function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:app_name` rather than `:db_name`, and pass in the name of an app-server that has the correct combination of documents database, and modules database. Otherwise the code is evaluated against the App-Services server, which runs against the out of the box, and typically empty Documents and Modules databases.

It would be nice if you could provide SJS code directly, and it would require only limited changes to Roxy. Add weight to this ticket to push its priority:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/issues/821

HTH!

Comment: Thanks! Re: the github ticket, I'm not super familiar with github, how do I "add weight to this ticket"? I think all I can do is comment on it?

Comment: You need to be logged in. After that you can post a comment or tag the issue or a comment with a smiley. A comment would be great, particularly if you describe your need..